# Can escaped ("\") symbols in code be converted?

Tags: feature-request

In [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11162/solving-a-pde-containing-diracdelta) I read the following code:

[image]

which I find, er, hard to read; I had to copy and paste it in Mathematica to make anything of it. Can the HTML preprocessor be updated so that "**\[Lambda]**" shows as "**λ**", etc.?

Comment: We have a syntax highlighter, not a preprocessor, for Mathematica code, so this might be too hard / processor-intensive for the server. A compromise solution might be an easy copy-and-paste CW for editing characters into questions?

Comment: Would that be copy-pastable back into *Mathematica*? I mean, a HTML `λ` might not be parsed as `\[Lambda]` by *Mathematica*.

Comment: @Verbeia - what's CW?

Comment: @István - How about a button "copy original code to clipboard"?

Comment: Or even an "evaluate-and-display-in-place" button in the browser :)

Comment: @Verbeia - Yes, it was either that or "clockwise" :-), but I don't understand the community wiki in this context. Can you explain what you mean? Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @István - That sounds like a great feature, but it may render a different result than what asker gets, and what she has problems with. And then the question becomes confusing.

Comment: @stevenvh a post marked community wiki, containing the code and the pastable Unicode nice glyph, to make it easier to edit.

Comment: @stevenvh I wouldn't want the system to automatically replace them... after all, a code block is supposed to show exactly what you paste. A userscript might be a better idea, and it should be easy to do for those who know javascript. I don't, but I use a vim script to convert all these in my code before posting and also use it to edit others' code quickly. It's just 1 command to replace it. It's also not trivial to copy as unicode in mma... see [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/how-to-copy-as-unicode-from-a-notebook)